# Shell Script para copiar estrutura de arquivos renomeando no destino

Tags: bash, shell-script

Gostaria de copiar uma estrutura de pastas já renomeando os arquivos para o seu destino colocando na frente do nome um texto informado previamente pelo usuário.

Mas estou com dificuldades para copiar renomeando os arquivos.

No script estou executando um `rsync`. Gostaria de executar um `find` para listar e copiar a estrutura e os arquivos criando um array, com isso poderia manipular o destino individualmente dentro de um loop `for` ou `while`.

Abaixo segue a estrutura de pasta e o script.

Pastas e arquivos de origem:

```
Template
    00 - Criação
        Arq de Criação.docx
        Arq de Informações.docx
    01 - Iniciação
        Arq de Iniciação.docx
        Arq de Coleta.docx
    02 - Planejamento
        Arq de Planejamento.docx
        Arq de Informações.docx
    03 - Execução
        Arq de Cronograma.docx
        Arq de Mudança.docx
    04 - Controle
        Arq de Entrega Parcial.docx
    05 - Encerramento
        Arq de AS Bult.docx
        Arq de Encerramento.docx
```

Pastas e arquivos de destino:

```
P20190103.0001 - Estrutura nova cliente
    00 - Criação
        P20190103.0001 - Arq de Criação.docx
        P20190103.0001 - Arq de Informações.docx
    01 - Iniciação
        P20190103.0001 - Arq de Iniciação.docx
        P20190103.0001 - Arq de Coleta.docx
    02 - Planejamento
        P20190103.0001 - Arq de Planejamento.docx
        P20190103.0001 - Arq de Informações.docx
    03 - Execução
        P20190103.0001 - Arq de Cronograma.docx
        P20190103.0001 - Arq de Mudança.docx
    04 - Controle
        P20190103.0001 - Arq de Entrega Parcial.docx
    05 - Encerramento
        P20190103.0001 - Arq de AS Bult.docx
        P20190103.0001 - Arq de Encerramento.docx
```

O código `P20190103.0001` é variável e inserido pelo usuário na execução do script.

```
#!/bin/bash
clear

LOCALMOUNTPOINT="/Volumes/Server01"

if mount | grep "on $LOCALMOUNTPOINT" > /dev/null; then
    echo ""
    echo ""
    echo ""
    echo "       Verificando se o volume esta montado.... OK"
    echo ""
    echo ""
    echo ""
    echo "       Informe o nome do projeto...: "
    read PROJETO
    FULLPATHSRC="/Users/xxx/Downloads/Templates/"
    FULLPATHDST="/Users/xxx/Downloads/teste/"$PROJETO"/"
    echo "       Criando estrutura do projeto: " $FULLPATHDST
    if [ -d "$FULLPATHDST" ] 
    then
       echo ""
       echo ""
       echo "      ERROR    "
       echo "     -------   "
       echo ""
       echo "Diretório de destino já existe...:"
       echo "  ---> $FULLPATHDST  <---" 
       echo ""
       echo ""
       echo ""
    else
       mkdir "$FULLPATHDST" > /dev/null;
       rsync -av --progress "$FULLPATHSRC" "$FULLPATHDST"
    fi
else
    echo ""
    echo ""
    echo "                            ERROR                         "
    echo "                           -------                        "
    echo ""
    echo "     Conecte-se ao servidor "Server01.dominio.local/Clientes""
    echo ""
    echo "            .....O volume não esta montado.....           "
    echo ""
    echo ""
    echo ""
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Após a execução do `rsync` você poderia rodar o `find` para listar todos arquivos copiados e renomear cada arquivo individualmente assim:

```bsh
# lista todos os arquivos copiados para $FULLPATHDST
find "$FULLPATHDST" -type f > /tmp/files.txt

# manipula cada arquivo indivualmente
while IFS='' read filepath; do
    # obtém o diretório do arquivo
    filedir="${filepath%/*}"
    # obtém o nome do arquivo (sem o diretório)
    filename="${filepath##*/}"
    # renomeia o arquivo conforme a necessidade - adiciona o prefixo
    mv -v "$filepath" "$filedir/P20190103.0001 - $filename"
done < /tmp/files.txt

rm -f /tmp/files.txt
```

O único problema é que o `rsync` não seria muito eficiente na segunda vez que seu script rodar, pois todos os arquivos estariam renomeados e o `rsync` iria copiá-los todos novamente.